# jquery ajax post href value without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello  I want to post link value e.g. 
href="?id=1"  my link

but without refreshing the page current it refreshes the page but i dont want reloading of the page, here is my code please help me

```
function loadTabContent(tabUrl){
    $("#preloader").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: post,
        url: tabUrl, 
        data: "id="+country_id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(message) {
        jQuery("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
        $("#preloader").hide();
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#preloader").hide(); 
    jQuery("[id^=tab]").click(function(){   

        // get tab id and tab url
        tabId = $(this).attr("id"); 
        tabUrl = jQuery("#"+tabId).attr("href");

        jQuery("[id^=tab]").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("#"+tabId).addClass("current");

        // load tab content
        loadTabContent(tabUrl);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
function loadTabContent(tabUrl){
    $("#preloader").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: post,
        url: tabUrl, 
        data: "id="+country_id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(message) {
        jQuery("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
        $("#preloader").hide();
        }
    });
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#preloader").hide(); 
    jQuery("[id^=tab]").click(function(e){   

        // get tab id and tab url
        tabId = $(this).attr("id"); 
        tabUrl = jQuery("#"+tabId).attr("href");

        jQuery("[id^=tab]").removeClass("current");
        jQuery("#"+tabId).addClass("current");

        // load tab content
        loadTabContent(tabUrl);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: OK but how to get data php file? Becuase when putting this and php code on the top of my page it loads the page main page again but i just want to grab some values from mysql

Comment: I've just edit part2 of your code, so you must enter part1 and part2 , i'm edit my answer now

Comment: @user3606257 Your issue has nothing to do with php or mysql.  If you need help with your php then you need to post your code.  But it sounds like this is a different issue so you should ask it in a new question.

Comment: its still refreshing i think becuase of href value is it possible to do this same thing with `data: "id="+country_id,` part and also with `href tag` just id tab id post data to php file to fetch from mysql table using `$_GET['id'];` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think return false should be fine unless your function is causing an exception to occur such as a bad ajax request.  Try putting quotes around the word post in the type attribute when you make the ajax call.  Also country_id is undefined, you should pass that too if you need it.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
function loadTabContent(tabUrl, country_id){
    $("#preloader").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: tabUrl, 
        data: "id="+country_id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(message) {
            jQuery("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
            $("#preloader").hide();
        }
    });
}
```